# Masking subfolder to a subdomain

Tags: linux, .htaccess, dns, subdomain, subdirectory

I wonder if it is possible to achieve this. We have 2 servers windows and linux. We would like  visitors go to http://www.mydonetserver.com/event will see exactly what we have setup for the subdomain http://event.myphpserver.com ?

Window Server (for .net) : http://www.mydonetserver.com/event
Linux Server (for .php)  : http://event.myphpserver.com

So effectively we want the subfolder on http://www.mydonetserver.com/event to function exactly like it is on http://event.myphpserver.com domain.

Would it possible to achieve without using iframe nor .htaccess redirect.

Many thanks

Comment: Sure, you can do that. The best solution depends on whether `www.mydonetserver.com` and `event.myphpserver.com` are handled by the same web server or not, and if yes, which web server software it is. Could you please update your question to include that info?

Comment: Hi Celada, thanks for your input. No, they are not on the same web servers.  http://www.mydonetserver.com is Windows server and completely separated to http://event.myphpserver.com - which is running on Apache (PHP) server.

Comment: OK then you'll want to configure the mydonetserver.com to [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to the other server for URLs beginning with http://mydonetserver.com/event . That's easy to do with Apache but I guess that MS Windows server is not running Apache. Someone who is familiar with it will have to answer.